# Symfony Fos user Bundle

Tags: fosuserbundle

I am quiet new to symfony 2 frmaework and I have been trying to find a inbuilt function or a fos container service that contains information about groups or role of a currently logged in user.I have used groups of FOS user bundle and each of user is assigned to only one group and role is defined to group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need information about assigned roles to user? If yes, then just call $user->getRoles() on user object. Or $user->hasRole($roleName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the symfony session object you will have the current logged in user, and because the group is mapped to the user entity you can just access to the group with a getter here is a twig example

`{{ app.security.getToken().getUser().getGroup() }}`

To get the group roles you just call the Geter getRoles (), it returns the user roles and his group roles in the same array.